# HTML & CSS : How do I change names and job titles to be under the pictures

Tags: html, css

How do I change names and job titles to be under the pictures.

Please follow this [link](http://dev.tasch.co.za/hope/en/who-we-are/senior-staff)

Comment: What do you mean by change names and job titles.

Comment: make question clear

Comment: I think he wants to remove the float of the image.

Comment: I want to move the name and title of each picture (each person) to be under the picture and NOT aside like it is at this moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove

```
float: left
```

From the img CSS rule, and you'll be fine. Next time, please provide some code or give a better explanation of what you want to achieve and which problems are you encountering.

Comment: Thanks ! Solved. How do I make the question solved??

Comment: You simply need to mark an answer as correct (the green check image).

Answer (score 1):

Remove Inline code from **p** tag i.e

```
p
{
float: left;
padding-left: 2%;
width: 60%;
}
```

and remove **float:left** from **img** tag